# How to only use the Google Drive interface (and not the Docs one)

Tags: google-drive

After the switch from Google Docs to Drive I've been trained to do everything through the Drive interface which I now prefer to the Docs one.

But for whatever reason the Docs interface is still lurking in the background and is ready to jump out and confuse me at any turn.

For example, if I open up a document from Drive, I can only get back to the Docs interface from within the document (like move to trash and the docs home button).

Is there anyway to just get redirected to the Drive interface every time?